# Apply the toggle for group in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am developing an SSRS report and want to apply toggle for the groups. My data from the stored procedure is as below,

```
Group     InitialName Value
Group     A           1000
Group     B           2000
Group     C           3000
Test1G1   All         300
Test1G2   A           200
Test1G3   B           100
Test2G1   All         300
Test2G2   A           200
Test2G3   B           100
```

Now I want to apply the toggle for the last 2 groups, but not for first group.

So the expected result should as below,

```
Group         InitialName Value
Group         A           1000
Group         B           2000
Group         C           3000
[+] Test1G1   All         300
[+] Test2G1   All         300
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156456(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Is it an option for you to exclude "Test#G1 ALL" from your stored procedure dataset? or it's just how it is?

Comment: @morinx It's just how it is.

Comment: @R.Richards I have tried it but it is not working as expected.